# Image Segmentation Based on Colour

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, image-segmentation

I was looking for ways to classify the different colours present in the bands of the resistor using openCV and python.

What algorithm can be used to segment the image into different bands etc. I tried using the watershed algorithm but i couldnt get the markers right and didnt get the desired results.

Sample Image I used: [image: img]

Comment: and why did you try watershed in the first place?

Comment: One approach:- Convert to HSV/HSI model and use https://github.com/saurabheights/IPExperimentTools/tree/master/AnalyzeHSV to find hue/saturation range.

Answer (score 0):

The possible colors of resistor codes are known apriori.
You could simply scan across the resistor and check which of those colors are present in which order.

The final implementation would of course depend on many things.

If you just have a random snapshot of a resistor it will be more difficult than having the same orientation, position, perspective and scale every time.

Finding the resistor and its main axis should be rather simple, then all you need is a scan line.

Another option: Transform the image to HUE, then use the resistors body colour and the background colour for two threshold operations, which should leave you with the colour bands.

Comment: Thanks a lot . ill Try using the HSV colour space and let you know with the results.